# how to Upload file from Form then send it using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, nodemailer

I am creating a small application where a user can fill out a form with there name, current employer, type of position, and a few more fields. At the end of the form I allow the user to upload and attach there resume.

I was wondering what is the best way to send the contents of the form along with the attached resume through nodemailer.

I already have the form data sending into an email once the form is submitted I just need to know the best way to handle the uploading of a file.

The process I am looking for is: User fills out the form along with there resume then send the contents of the form along with the resume to an email. I don't want to save anything.

**What I've tried:**

- I tried using multer. However when I add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to my form tags  `<form action="/jobrequest" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` the `req.body` object stops sending the contents of the form.

this is my app configuration file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const router = require('./router')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const session = require('express-session')
const flash = require('connect-flash')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(cookieParser('secret'))
app.use(session({
    secret: 'SECRET-KEY-NOT-REAL',
    cookie: {maxAge: null},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))

app.use(flash())
app.set('views', 'views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use('/', router)
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).render('404')
  })
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack)
    res.status(500).render('404')
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

Comment: I don't see multer being used in your config.

Comment: Upload the file using multer